# Is there a way to resize a window to specific sizes (eg.800x600, 1024x768..)?

Tags: windows, window

I need a way to resize any window (**not** just Firefox!) to specific sizes.

I need to check what the application I'm writing looks like at these resolutions - how many columns are visible in grids, that sort of thing.

I know I could just change my resolution, but that's a hassle, especially for 800x600 - desktop icons get smooshed together and stuff.

Comment: Still, changing the screen resolution also takes the taskbar into account. So, when only resizing application windows, then be sure to make it a bit smaller to account for the *available* screen estate.

Comment: @Arjan: for Chrome, several web extensions offer a way to exactly set the viewport. See f.ex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46998025/how-to-create-a-1280x800-screenshot (by me)

Comment: @serv-inc, while true, that's not what this question is about.

Comment: VTR as this is easily phrased as a *how do I achieve X*, not necessarily a *give me a program to X*

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Check out [Sizer](http://www.brianapps.net/sizer) ...

> Sizer is a tiny freeware utility that
>   gives you an easy and fast way to
>   resize any window to an exact size. It
>   could be a very useful tool for
>   webmasters and web designers.

Comment: Excellent! That's a very slick program. I hope it eventually supports vista/win7 but for now I'm still on XP anyway. Thanks :)

Comment: I have it running under Vista on my main dev box at work without issue.

Comment: @David Spillett: Curious - are you running Vista x86 or x64?

Comment: Problem is there is no version for Windows 7 - 64 Bit :( i've used Sizer for years and now I can't.

Comment: The 64bit version is currently under development, but available for download. Works on my machine(tm)

Comment: I can confirm that Sizer still works under 64-bit Windows 10.

Comment: it works on windows 10, but it does not work with certain windows like "Device Manager"

Comment: Great! That was what I'm looking for. Here is a link to the modernized version [Sizer4](https://www.brianapps.net/sizer4/)

Answer (score 42):

You could write your own with [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/):

```
#=:: ; [Win]+[=]
    WinGet, window, ID, A
    InputBox, width, Resize, Width:, , 140, 130
    InputBox, height, Resize, Height:, , 140, 130
    WinMove, ahk_id %window%, , , , width, height
    return
```

---

### Demonstration:

**Before: 640 x 480**

[image: before]

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>.
2. Enter a width:

   [image: width]
3. Enter a height:

   [image: height]

**After: 400 x 300**

[image: after]

> **Note:** To set a length to `0`, you have to input `0`. An empty value is ignored. For example, if you only want to resize the height, leave the width blank and enter a value for the height.

---

*For the curious: **0 x 0***

[image: smallest]

*As you can see, a window with a title bar and controls has an absolute minimum size.*

Comment: For those interested, Here is a similar approach to change one of the four (X,Y,width,height) of active window. [autohotkey: how to resize window by both absolute and relative height](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46809005/3625404)

Comment: I set a window in W10 to 960x540, but the result is 946x533. Do I need to add a value for the title bar and scrolling bar, so its more an inner dimension than an outer?

Comment: @mgutt Same for me. I've found that it can be worked around on a per-application basis with code such as the following just before the line `WinMove`:
`if WinActive("ahk_exe chrome.exe") {
 width += 16
 height += 8
}`

Answer (score 3):

I like the AutoHotkey solution of @iglvzx, but the code posted only works in AutoHotkey v1. Here is working code for AutoHotkey v2:

```autohotkey
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0-
#Warn
#SingleInstance

#=::resizeWindow(WinGetID("A")) ; [Win]+[=]

resizeWindow(window) {
    WinGetPos , , &W, &H, window
    width := InputBox("Width: " W "px", "Resize", "w100 h84", W - Mod(W, 4))
    if (width.Result = "OK") {
        height := InputBox("Height: " H "px", "Resize", "w100 h84", H - Mod(H, 4))
        if (height.Result = "OK") {
            WinMove , , width.Value, height.Value, window
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Extra features in here: it shows the current width and height in the popups and suggested the next smaller value rounded to 4px. Adapt to your liking :-)

Comment: I like this solution except it does an outer size, not an inner size

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [WinSize2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winsize2/).

- Simple, fast, and easy to manage by using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> And <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> keys to **increase/decrease the size** of the current window.
- Working on any Windows version, or at least I have tested it on Windows XP, 7 and 8.
- **Free** Software.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to the latest versions of Windows 10 (2021) I had the best luck with [Window Resizer](https://github.com/caoyue/WindowResizer)

I always have 3 browser windows open and I prefer all of them to be the exact same size all over lapping each other spot on.  Plus I greatly dislike having a ton of things running in the notification area.  You can run this app, restore your windows then close the app.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it was a coincidence, but right after installing SIZER my Windows interface totally malfunctioned - the start menu got transparent windows was not refreshing and I could not click anything. I had to disable transparency in Windows 10 to fix this. Did anyone have such an issue too?

I ended up using this : https://www.mindgems.com/article/resize-window-to-specific-size-set-window-size-in-pixels/

Actually, I am quite happy with it as it is really easy. If you press CTRL+SHIF+R on any window a dialog appears and you can enter the sizes that you want. The current size of the window is displayed too.

On top of that, you can capture and annotate screenshots too. Give it a try I am sure
you will love it. I tested it on Windows 10 and 11 and it does the job perfectly.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the [WS Grid+ Window Manager](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/9NBZ8NL2F408?hl=en-us&gl=US). It costs 4.99 EUR but there is a 7-days trial for you to test.

I am using it with Windows 11 and it works great:

[image: WS Grid+ Window Manager]

Answer (score 0):

With powertoys fancy zones this can be achived pretty neatly. Define a fancyzone of the desired size by dragging. It shows the size in realtime so pretty easy. When the zone is defined and enabled, you can drag any window while holding shift will allow you to release the window in the zone you defined before and it will resize to fill the zone.