# Resize a window without being limited by screen resolution in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, window

Context : I am a system validation engineer and in my current project i'm testing fonctionalities of Human–machine interface (HMI) in industrial systems.

Problem : The HMI are designed for big screens (high display resolutions) and my laptop has an average screen size. Concequently, when I'm running some HMI softwares a lot of buttons are not displaying at all. (My OS is Windows 7) According to my collegues, in former Windows OS versions ( XP for instance ), it was possible to increase the size of window to make it bigger than the actual size of the screen (in lenght for instance). Then it was possible to see all the buttons of an HMI using scrollbars ! This is not possible anymore in Windows 7 since the windows size is bounded by the size of the screen... :'(

My question is : Is it possible to change some Windows 7 "paramaters" in order to remove the window size limitation ?

I hope someone has a solution,

regards

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is an option for you but I've figured out a way to do this on my Windows 7 machine with a virtual machine in VMware Player 5.0.1 build-894247.

- My monitor is 1280x1024
- My VM is a Windows XP install
- I can crank my resolution up to 3840x1920 in the Windows XP VM

[image]

This will provide scrollbars on the right and bottom of my VM which allows me to scroll around in the giant Windows XP resolution.

I do not know if this would work with a Windows 7 VM

I do not know if Oracle Virtualbox supports this.

Comment: Thank you MonkeyZeus, it seems to work well but unfortunatly this is not an option for me as I'm not allowed to install a Windows VM on my computer.

What am I actually looking for is a solution that involves kind of a modification of some Windows 7 parameters or the use of a very simple software.

I'm keeping your solution in mind !

Comment: @Muppet32 You're welcome, hopefully something comes to light for you! Not sure if this thread would be helpful but you can check it out: http://superuser.com/questions/18215/program-to-resize-any-window-to-specific-sizes-eg-800x600-1024x768